# Installing NVIDIA drivers within VIRTUALENV

Tags: virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia

So this may seem unusual - but I am using a remote server with linux and gpus. The GPUS have old drivers and I do not have permission to update them. Can I do that within a virtualenv? The goal is then to use CUDA 10 +CUDNN and do all the nice things possible with the recent versions of these software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtualenv` only concerns Python interpreter and its packages. It cannot handle hardware drivers - you absolutely need root permissions to install a hardware driver. Your best bet would be to contact the administrators of the server and ask them to upgrade. Alternately you can rent your own server, which is not at all as expensive as it used to be (e.g. from AWS).